# How to customize the login page of vBulletin 4

Tags: vbulletin

I am using vBulletin version 4.1.4. I want to re-design the login page (it is separated with current vBulletin skin), I have tried using these instructions http://www.vbgeeko.com/archives/217 but it shows an error:

```
Warning: fetch_template() calls should be replaced by the vB_Template class. Template name: navbar in [path]\includes\functions.php on line 4114

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\wamp\www\vBulletin Forum v4.1.4\upload\clogin.php(42) : eval()'d code on line 1
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  374496  {main}( )   ..\clogin.php:0

Warning: fetch_template() calls should be replaced by the vB_Template class. Template name: clogin in [path]\includes\functions.php on line 4114
```

So how can I make a custom login page of vBulletin 4?